# OutOfMemoryError while writing JSon array to out put stream

Tags: java, json

I have Java program and I am reading from file of Size Approx 40GB and converting data on fly and streaming to DataOutputstream.

Below is my code

```
    JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                 JSONObject properties = new JSONObject(); 

           while((strLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                {


            if (jsonArray.length()%100 == 0) {

                    printJsonData(jsonArray);
            //      sendJsonData(jsonArray, output);
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                }

if (strLine.trim().contains("data")) {
                        jsonObj.put("properties",properties);
                        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

    if (strLine.trim().contains("data1")) {
                String secondPart = strLine.split(":",2)[1];
                properties.put("data1", secondPart);    
                continue;
                }
            if (strLine.trim().contains("id")) {
                String secondPart = strLine.split(":",2)[1];
                jsonObj.put("id", secondPart ); 
            continue;

            }

    }
```

I have two methods one is printing JSON data and other is sending Json data over https.

```
private void printJsonData(JSONArray jsonArray) {
      int count = jsonArray.length(); // get totalCount of all jsonObjects
      for(int i=0 ; i< count; i++){   // iterate through jsonArray 
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);  // get jsonObject @ i position 
            System.out.println("jsonObject " + i + ": " + jsonObject);
        }
    }

private void sendJsonData(JSONObject jsonObj,DataOutputStream   output) throws IOException {

    int count = jsonArray.length();     

    for(int i=0 ; i< count; i++) {   // iterate through jsonArray 
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);  // get jsonObject @ i position 
        System.out.println("Sending Data-->" + jsonObject.toString());
        output.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString()); 
    }
}
```

Whenver i call print method, every thing works fine. But when i call sendJsonData method. I am getting OutofMemoryerror. Wondering how to fix it?

Comment: Where are you getting the value of count in the sendJsonData method?

Comment: er, can not even see where `sendJsonData` is called from

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis int count = jsonArray.length();  I fixed it. thanks

Comment: @ScaryWombat I commented the line in while loop for sending data: call is sendJsonData(jsonArray, output);

Comment: What is the output stream inside the DataOutputStream?

Comment: @efekctive it is connected with https URL ->  URL url = new URL(https_url);
   HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/plain"); 
 
   connection.setDoOutput(true); 
   connection.setDoInput(true); 
 output =  new DataOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not manipulating json in any way I would treat as a text file and send it that way. The likelihood of finding a big JsonObject is good so you may be pushing through too much.

An array of 40gb is awfully big array unless there are huge objects.

** EDIT **

Or you could treat the individual json objects as "files" and push those strings individually

Comment: Meaning One Object at a time? and No array at all?

Comment: I would try to launch a connection per array element. Treat each element as an string and make an stream of them and send them in a more controlled manner. Maybe you could launch a thread pool to speed things up. Reading the whole thing line by line may be too slow

Comment: You option for sending One Big Array at a time with one connection help fix this issue. -- Thans Ammad